# illegal string offset 'name' when working with password fields laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I'm having a problem. I create form by laravel. I'm working with text field succesfully but when working with password field = error. Who help me? Thank guys.

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
{!! Form::label('name','Username') !!}
{!! Form::text('txtname','',array('class'=>'user')) !!}
{!! Form::label('pass','Password') !!}
{!! Form::password('txtpass','',array('class'=>'user')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Form Password does not have *value* parameter. So the correct form is:

`{!! Form::password('txtpass', array('class'=>'user')) !!}`

Answer (score 1):

Please Change the Line of password Field to this

```
{!! Form::password('txtpass',array('class'=>'user')) !!}
```